# Is clock usage recommended in VHDL design?

Tags: vhdl, fpga, digital-design

I am doing a small task where I have to count the pulses coming from two inputs. The requirement doesn't specify clock. Currently I have a process that is triggered when any of the input changes and then corresponding count is increased.
My question is Should I use clock for this design and make the process Clock sensitive and then check if inputs have Changed? Is it a good practice to use Clocks in VHDL design?

Sub-question- I have to double buffer the input data. Does this mean I have to use clock and pass inputs through two flipflops? or is there a way to double buffer data without using clock?

Comment: Why do you have to double-buffer the input data?

Comment: @Harry The data might have meta-stability. So to avoid this, as part of requirement, I have to double buffer the data.

Comment: This means you must *register* the signal twice (using whatever clock will be used for the subsequent processing). So, the answer to your question is yes - you do need a clock. Note that the answer to your question is about the hardware you need to describe. (It's actually not about VHDL. VHDL is just a tool you use to describe the hardware).

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to design asynchronous circuit with VHDL. The design rules are a bit different than synchronous design (using request and acknoledge signals).

Your need is not very complex and could be designed without clock but you have to be careful with your memorisation element. Specialy if you work with an FPGA, these devices are not supposed to work asynchonously. So look carefully the synthetizer results.

(If it's school homework, use a clock ;) In digital design, the clock usage is the default case. Asynchronous logic is an advanced concept)